# Can someone help me modify my script? To exit sub on error after line 7?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, exit-code

```
Sub shutdownbot()



Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = Application.Calculation =xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Windows("FlaggingreportBOTv2.xlsb").Activate  
Windows("Post 7am routing risk level v5.2.xlsb").Activate.
```

‘when the end user opens the file I
expect this line to error then exit the sun with any error messages on screen being supressed

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `On error resume next`.

As you should use this very carefully it is recommended to **always** comment, why you think it is ok to use `On error resume next` in this case.
And reset the error handling as soon as possible by inserting `On error goto 0` or `On error goto xxx`

```vb
Sub shutdownbot()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = Application.Calculation =xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Windows("FlaggingreportBOTv2.xlsb").Activate  

‘when the end user opens the file I expect this line to error then exit the sun with any error messages on screen being supressed

On error resume next
Windows("Post 7am routing risk level v5.2.xlsb").Activate. 
On error goto 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

End sub
```

Comment: no joy when , im trying to the macro to stop when the file name is has been changed from this Post 7am routing risk level v5.2.xlsb to same with date and time?